# MongoShell populate is not function?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-populate, mongo-shell

i am working with MongoDB. i came across with an issue that i was trying to query data through MongoShell. but when i tried to run "populate" query from MongoShell, i gave error ".populate is not a function".
why populate query is not working in MongoShell.
i studied an article it says that populate is the function which is provided by mongoose library for Nodejs only, its not native supported by MongoDB.
but in another article its mentioned that "populate" query is supported by MongoDB version above 4.2.
i have version 7. but i'm still getting this error,
I do not know why?

Comment: Show what you have tried so far (code) in a [**Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [**How to Ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: What was the latter article that suggested it was supported?

Comment: i have tried this query ' db.collection_2.find().pupolate("userId")'. but im running this query in mongoshell, im not trying it through mongoose.

Comment: The [Model.populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) method is part of the Mongoose library and is **not** one of the [mongosh methods](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/). Perhaps the author meant something else. Do you have a link to the article?

Comment: I tried to search out that article but unfortunately i could not find it.
but thank you for your response and i studied more about it.
populate() is not available in mongosh, its mongoose provided method.

Answer (score -1):

[i found it there](https://medium.com/@truong.minh.michael/when-to-use-find-vs-aggregate-lookup-vs-populate-in-mongoose-and-mongodb-5a08f650639f)

populate() is provided by mongoose library, its not provided by mongodb. its not available in mongoshell functions as well.